# FlipView shows only first Items

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have some code similar to this:

```
<FlipView UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" SelectedItem="{Binding Record, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:Record">
            <TextBlock x:Name="debugText" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            <UC:MyControl Record="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

`MyControl` needs the date to be converted with `myConverter`, and then it shows the detail information of Record. It shows an image, the name, etc.
The `TextBlock` `debugText` is created for debugging purposes.

When I move the `FlipView` by hand or by code, the elements are transitioning correctly. I can debug how the `SelectedItem` is updated correctly, and I can see the `debugText` updating correctly.

But for some reason, `MyControl` cycling between the first items. It is showing only the 3 or 4 first items, and after arriving at 3th or 4th, it starts again showing the first one. I debug the converter `myConverter`, and I can see that it is called 3 or 4 times loading the view. But then it not called anymore, even when I transition to the next elements.

It shows only the 3 first elements when `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="False"`, and it shows the 4 first elements when `UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="True"`.

I can manage to show all the items correctly, by writting the `FlipView.ItemsPanel`:

```
<FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemsPanel>
```

But it is not a solution for me, because there are many `Records` (can be more than 300), and done in this way the page takes so long in loading, and wastes so much memory. When I run it in this mode in a phone, the application even crashes when there are many records.

How can I make it work for more than the 3 or 4 first items?

Comment: I can not see your how do you create `UC:MyControl`, so I can't reproduce your problem. So please post your more complete code about `UC:MyControl`. If you want display an image, the name, etc. You can put them in the `DataTemplate` with `Grid`.

Comment: Sorry, it is very big to adapt an working example for here. I was able to solve it by adding `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` to the `FlipView`.